# Get the value at any given point in a non-linear transition?

Tags: c++, graph

I wrote a simple function that gives me the value at any given point in a linear transition from 0 to 1:

```
float getValueAtPosition(int position, int length)
{
    return 1.0f / length * position;
}
```

[image: linear transition]

Setting the position to 50 (if the length of the transition is 100) will return 0.5

```
getValueAtPosition(50, 100); //returns 0.5
```

I want to add a parameter to my function to control how "curved" the transition is, like so:

[image: non-linear transitions]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have an equation for those functions? Cause you'll solve for a point along a logarithmic or exponential curve just as you solve for a point along a linear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! No I don't - that's what I'm struggling with! I've been trying to write a few but I don't understand how to come up with a logarithmic curve that 1. will be symmetrical (inside the scope of the transition) 2. will let me implement it and control the amount of "curviness" with a parameter, from "almost square" to straight line to "almost square" again (but exponential). Sorry if I'm being unclear, I really lack some vocabulary here..

Comment: What do you mean by *"almost square"* ?

Comment: That the curve is so sharp that it's starting to resemble a corner of a square. for instance y=x^90

Comment: @Daggepagge I'd suggest that you close this question and open one on http://math.stackexchange.com/ asking how to make an equation that will give you such a curve. Once you know your equations if you're still having trouble then you could open a new question on http://www.stackoverflow.com asking how to implement those equations in functions.